# alternatives to optional statements to reduce redundant rows

Tags: sparql, rdf

I am using SPARQL to create a table with a lot of optional statements, the problem is that i end up with a lot of redundant data. is there another way of collecting OPTIONAL data without 4 or 5 discrete optional statements? I thought about using a UNION between all the OPTIONAL statements, but that did not do what I wanted.

Not really looking for a specific solution, just other alternative statements or techniques I can try.

Thanks!

Comment: unclear what you're asking ... please provide some sample data. the current query, the current result and the expected result. Thank you

Comment: Is `COALESCE` what you need?